# Mixing static html pages with the angular 6+

Tags: html, angular, routes

What is the best practice when it comes mixing static html pages with the angular 6+ apps without writing empty components for each of those pages?

static pages such as ...

- https://myapp.com/aboutus.html
- https://myapp.com/contactus.html
- https://myapp.com/news/whatever-news-article.html

Comment: Do you have a backend from which you can get the content for the pages?

Comment: You could make one component that hold static pages that show the right content based by some conditions using `*ngIf`

Comment: @Arcteezy yes we do have

Comment: @HrishikeshJadhav Then try my solution. I use such a method for similar use cases.

Comment: @Arcteezy  need to serve static files locally with ng serve,

Comment: @HrishikeshJadhav Then instead of server store the HTML strings in a JSON file and use it to populate the `innerHTML`. But thats a bad practice and will bulk the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-build with your index.html set properly with its components. (or conditional app-components)
rename and copy the rendered to (for example) /src/assests/aboutus.html
in angular.json find "assets":

 "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets",
      "src"
    ],
browse localhost:4200/aboutus.html directly.
Always place the static contents in assets folder, thats a good practice.
```